# How to batch move/delete files on FTP using scripts

Tags: batch-file, ftp, data-cleaning

I currently use Globalscapes CuteFTP as my FTP client and am in the process of cleaning up old, unused files. I use a script to upload new files to the FTP but that is based on a wildcard; uploading anything I have in a specific folder.

Now I want to do the opposite and delete files but only specific files. I have a list of over 1,000 file names that I need to remove (or ideally move to a designated folder) but I am not sure how to write the script to do this. Could someone help me create a batch relocate script or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: I could use something like this but that is a lot of manual work. Is there a way to reference a batch list or no?


MySite.Connect

MySite.RemoteRename "/current-folder/file-name.jpg", "/archive/file-name.jpg"

MySite.Disconnect

Comment: So you have a list of a file names in a text file (or similar) and you want to convert that list to a FTP script to delete those files? Is it one-off task, or will you be doing this regularly?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have better luck looking for some FTP client that allows scriptable actions.  A quick search pointed out http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting which might be helpful.

Comment: Question asked as quoted from the OP "Could someone help me create a batch relocate script or at least point me in the right direction?" can you point out exactly where it indicates the location of the files?

Comment: Apologies, serves me right for trying to answer questions while sleepy!  I've edited the answer to include a more on-topic answer.  Script the FTP commands.